# Delete data of particular week

Tags: javascript, database

I need to delete data automatically from database table  which is 3 weeeks ago.Take this week as week 10, i need to delete data of(10-2)  week 08. Here week no is dynamic. It keep on changing .So if i'm making an entry in week 12 data of week 10 should get deleted from the table.

Comment: You can use scheduling task to perform deletion action from databse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options.

**1.Event Scheduler**

First create table and create event for perform delete query for delete 3 weeks ago record.

```
CREATE EVENT `ex1` ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
ENABLE
COMMENT ''
DO BEGIN
DELETE FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),TimeStampColumn) > 21

END
//for 3 weeks
```

Note : Old versions of mysql don't have event scheduler

**2. Create cron job**

**file1.sql**

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),TimeStampColumn) > 21
```

**schedule this command:**

mysql -uusername -ppassword < /path/to/file1.sql